# Overlay when click on menu (and remove border)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my name is Daniel and im working on my portfolio website. I want an overlay when i click on my hamburger menu so that everything becomes darker and the focus lays on the menu. And i want it to go away when you click on the menu again, or click on one of the menu items or click on the overlay self. (only for my mobile version)

Also i have weird border-line when i open my hamburger menu on mobile and i don't know how to remove it

Link to my website so far: http://20162.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/portfoliowebsite/

(the latest version isn't online yet)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Daniel Gotz">
  <title>Daniel Gotz | Porfolio </title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="dist/hamburgers.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:600,900|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->   
  <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
          <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin navbar-toggle visible-xs" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class=" hamburger-box">
    <span class=" hamburger-inner"></span> </span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav right">
            <li class="hidden">
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#intro">Intro</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#mijnwerk">Mijn werk</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#overdaniel">Over Daniel</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>


       <div class="title">
      <h1> Every mountain top is within reach if you just keep climbing</h1> </div>

      <div class="berg">
    <img src="berg.svg">


      </div>


  </section>
  <section id="mijnwerk" class="about-section"> </section>
  <section id="overdaniel" class="services-section"> </section>
  <section id="contact" class="contact-section"> </section>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/hamburgers.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.overflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.home {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.mijnwerk {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #27ae60;
}


.navbar-default {
  background: none;
  border-color: transparent;
    z-index: 3;  
}

.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;



}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 14px;



}

.nav>li>a {
  padding: 15px 25px;
    border-style: none;



}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #ecf0f1;
      border-style: none;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: none


}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-style: none;



}



h1 {

  font-family:  'Exo 2' , sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 37px;
  line-height: 60px;


}

.title {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.berg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0  0 -2px 0;

}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {

    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

.intro-section {
    height: 100%;
    background: #2ecc71;
    color: white;
  text-align: center;


}

.about-section {
    height: 100%;
    background: #27ae60;
}

.services-section {
    height: 100%;
    background: #3498db;
}

.contact-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}
```

JS:

```
// Look for .hamburger
  var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  // On click
  hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Toggle class "is-active"
    hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
    // Do something else, like open/close menu
  });
```

I hope someone can help me out with these problems! :)

Answer (score 0):

With this config you just pass background to the menu, and the close button will not be included and remove the border.

```
 .navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse collapse in {
        background: rgba(27, 27, 62, 0.5);
    }

 .navbar-default {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    z-index: 3;
    }
```

Comment: this didn't do anything